# Newest PHP and preg_replace()

Tags: php, preg-replace, deprecated, preg-replace-callback

Welcome.

I have problem, becouse when I installed newest Xampp I have errors on my website, but I can not PHP and I do not know how to repair it.

Error content:

> Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use
>   preg_replace_callback instead in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\EXTREME\system\bbcodes\mail.php on line 35

Mail.php content:

```
<?php defined('EF5_SYSTEM') || exit;

$_locale->load('mail');

$bbcode_info = array(
    'name' => __('Mail'),
    'description' => __('Displays the text as an e-mail address'),
    'value' => 'mail'
);

if($bbcode_used)
{
    $text = preg_replace('#\[mail=([\r\n]*)([^\s\'\";:\]*?)\](.*?)([\r\n]*)\[/mail\]#sie', "'<a href=\'http://mailto:'.HELP::hide_email('\\2').'\' target=\'_blank\' title=\''.HELP::hide_email('\\2', '\\2').'\'>'.HELP::hide_email('\\2').'</a>'", $text);
    $text = preg_replace('#\[mail\]([\r\n]*)([^\s\'\";:\]*?)([\r\n]*)\[/mail\]#sie', "'<a href=\'http://mailto:'.HELP::hide_email('\\2').'\' target=\'_blank\' title=\''.HELP::hide_email('\\2').'\'>'.HELP::hide_email('\\2').'</a>'", $text);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without the `e` modifier, as suggested by the error message

```
<?php defined('EF5_SYSTEM') || exit;

$_locale->load('mail');

$bbcode_info = array(
    'name' => __('Mail'),
    'description' => __('Displays the text as an e-mail address'),
    'value' => 'mail'
);

if($bbcode_used)
{
    $text = preg_replace('#\[mail=([\r\n]*)([^\s\'\";:\]*?)\](.*?)([\r\n]*)\[/mail\]#si', "'<a href=\'http://mailto:'.HELP::hide_email('\\2').'\' target=\'_blank\' title=\''.HELP::hide_email('\\2', '\\2').'\'>'.HELP::hide_email('\\2').'</a>'", $text);
    $text = preg_replace('#\[mail\]([\r\n]*)([^\s\'\";:\]*?)([\r\n]*)\[/mail\]#si', "'<a href=\'http://mailto:'.HELP::hide_email('\\2').'\' target=\'_blank\' title=\''.HELP::hide_email('\\2').'\'>'.HELP::hide_email('\\2').'</a>'", $text);
}
```

I've changed `#sie` to `#si` in both lines.

The `e` modifier allowed you to evaluate PHP code in your regular expression, but now it's deprecated and shouldn't be used any longer. And you didn't need it anyway.